# Fitting logistic function giving strainght line in python?

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a logistic function to the data below. I am not able to understand why I get a straight line with fitted parameters? Can someone please help me with this?

```
x = [473,523,573,623,673]
y = [104,103,95,79,83]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

def f(x,a,b,c,d):
    return a/(1+np.exp(-c*(x-d))) + b

popt, pcov = opt.curve_fit(f,x,y,method="trf")
y_fit = f(x,*popt)
plt.plot(x,y,'o')
plt.plot(x,y_fit,'-')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good choice of initial values can make the difference between a successful optimization and one that fails. For this particular problem I would suggest the initial values that you can find in the code below (`p0` list). These values allows to properly estimate the covariance.

Moreover, you don't need to use the `trf` algorithm since you are not providing any bound (see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)). The Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm is the right tool for this case.

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = [473, 523, 573, 623, 673]
y = [104, 103, 95, 79, 83]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)


def f(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a / (1 + np.exp(-c * (x - d))) + b

p0 = [20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(f, x, y, p0=p0)
y_fit = f(x, *popt)
plt.plot(x, y, "o")
plt.plot(x, y_fit, "-")
plt.show()
```

[image]

If possible I would also suggest to increase the number of observations.

Comment: Thanks @blunova Appreciate the feedback.